# php. why are there exceptions of different classes? ex: PDOException vs Exception?

Tags: php, exception

Ok. very much totally noob question but I really don't have a clue and couldn't find  a definitive answer:

Why there are different exception classes? For exemple: PDOException vs Exception?
the way it goes through my brain: if something wrong happened in the code - exception will be thrown - right? why does it matter what type of exception?

**example:**

```
try {
     some code
}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

**vs Exception class:**

```
try {
     some code
}
catch(Exception $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Thanks:)

Comment: In PHP 7.4 Upgrade Notes: _"Attempting to serialize a PDO or PDOStatement instance will now generate an Exception rather than a PDOException, consistent with other internal classes which do not support serialization."_ [Here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.4/UPGRADING) is the source.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you should not treat all exception in the same way.

If you catch an exception, you could/should display an error message. But you could/should do some other things. And it will depend of the kind of exception you received.

If there is no db connection -> display message

If a query failed -> display a message and maybe do a rollback

...

Finally, you should catch all kind of exception and the last one should be `Exception`

```
try {
 some code
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
    // Do something
}
catch(XYZException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
    // Do something different
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Different exceptions can alternatively provide additional information. Eg. in case of PDO exception, you can retrieve the PDO error info with the `errorInfo` member: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php#pdoexception.props.errorinfo

If you used the `Exception` class you would have no access to this information.

Another reason is that it's a convenient way to specifically handle different types of exceptions if you have a try/catch block around a larger block of code, which can throw more than one type of exception. For example if you had an exception describing that a connection failed, you might want to try to re-connect in the catch handler. However if you have a generic exception catch handler, you just might want to log the message; You "chain" catch handlers to handle multiple types of exceptions:

```
try {
    // ... code
} catch (ConnectionException $e) {
   // try to reconnect
} catch (Exception $e) {
   // log exception
}
```

**Note.** ConnectionException is just an example to demonstrate my point how you might want to use a specific exception type to do something based on that exception, it's not a standard exception.

Answer (score 1):

Because then you can distinct beetween exceptions from different components.

```
try {
  do_something();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "PDO failed";
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "Unknown component failed";
}
```

Its not a good idea to make a "catch-all"-expression (except, it is really want is wanted: "catch all") and on the other hand is also not a good idea to throw a "Exception"-exception, because then you cannot distinct beetween this and any other exception anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Because you may have to do something different depending on the type of exception :

- If you catch a PDOException, you may want to rollback the current transaction, or log the SQL query.
- If you have a RuntimeException while opening a file with SplFileObject, you can know the file could not be opened
- …

Arguably exceptions are not very common in PHP right now, so catching specific exceptions is 99% of the time pointless (since you are only expecting one), but that doesn't stop you from using your own in your classes.

Answer (score 1):

Some exceptions you may want to deal with (hens the try/catch) and others you may want to handle at a higher level in your application. Having Exceptions of a different type allows you to choose the types of exception you may need to handle dependant on the task at hand.

for example: if you send an email but it throws an exception of its own type/class you may want your application to continue but log the error, but a more generic exception may require your application to be killed entirely.

It allows you to structure your error handling.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions can have different logic. For instance not all exceptions should result in a fatal. Some Exception will allow you to resume after catching them.

Every class should have it's own exception handler

1. because every class implementation differs. And so does the error / exception logic.
2. This way you can easily track what package / class throws an exception